# Restrict Administrator to Stop Service in VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, service, admin, administrator

I've observed that some services of my security software are not able to stop even from the administrator account. Star/ Stop option of those services are disabled.
I want to write that type of service in vb.net 2010 so that no user ( neither admin nor normal user) can stop the service.

Comment: I'm curious about your motivation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set [CanStop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase.canstop.aspx) = True in the properties of your service in VS.

> Gets or sets a value indicating whether the service can be stopped
>   once it has started.

Comment: thanks. this is exactly what I asked.
Can I close other services (which does not have Start/Stop option) forcibly using my service?

Comment: @AdnanHossain: Sounds like another question, not relevant to this one. Please post separately. If this answer solves your original issue, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it as an answer.

Comment: @AdnanHossain All processes *can* be forcibly stopped, although some require additional tools to do so (and also cause the system to reboot).

Comment: Hi, can u pls guide one? Recommend anything?

Comment: @AdnanHossain: I don't mind helping you with this, but please follow the rules of StackOverflow and post different issues separately.